# load data from csv into Scikit learn SVM

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to train a SVM to perform a classification of samples. I have a csv file with me that has 3 columns with headers: feature 1,feature 2, class label and 20 rows(= number of samples).

Now I quote from the Scikit-Learn documentation 
" As other classifiers, SVC, NuSVC and LinearSVC take as input two arrays: an array X of size [n_samples, n_features] holding the training samples, and an array y of class labels (strings or integers), size [n_samples]:"

I understand that I need to obtain two arrays(one 2d & one 1d array) in order to feed data into the SVM. However I am unable to understand how to obtain the required array from the csv file. 
I have tried the following code

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')
print data
```

However it is showing an error 
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: ��ࡱ�"

There are no column headers in the csv. Am I making any mistake in calling the function np.loadtxt or should something else be used?

Update: 
Here's how my .csv file looks like.

```
12  122 34
12234   54  23
23  34  23
```

Comment: Would be useful to see the first few lines of your csv

Comment: Hi I've updated the question with few lines of the csv.

Comment: I see no delimiter in your csv, remove the `delimiter` param so: `data = np.loadtxt('test.csv')` should work

Comment: It is also possible that the delimiter is a tab (look at how the values are aligned).  If that is the case, try `delimiter='\t'`.

Comment: @EdChum- yes now I notice the absence of commas.

Comment: So has this resolved your issue?

Comment: Yes it is solved. I am using Kingsoft excel to create the csv file. It was not getting saved in the right format(with commas). This can be verified by opening the csv file using notepad. If the format is saved correctly, we should notice commas between the data. If some gibberish comes then its not saved properly. I was getting gibberish. So I made a new csv file and saved it in .csv. Then I verified it by opening it in notepad. Now  loadtxt() is working. Thanks a lot for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the param `delimiter=','` but your csv was not comma separated.

So the following works:

```
In [378]:

data = np.loadtxt(path_to_data)
data
Out[378]:
array([[  1.20000000e+01,   1.22000000e+02,   3.40000000e+01],
       [  1.22340000e+04,   5.40000000e+01,   2.30000000e+01],
       [  2.30000000e+01,   3.40000000e+01,   2.30000000e+01]])
```

The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) show that by default the delimiter is `None` and so treats whitespace as the delimiter:

> delimiter : str, optional The string used to separate values. By
>   default, this is any whitespace.

Comment: As I said the problem was with the csv file and not the delimiter. I think changing the delimiter to ' ' is not going to work  because when a csv file is created, its delimiter is ',', dont you agree?

Comment: yes, you are right. I confirmed it from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values. However I was creating my csv file with the impression that the delimiter was comma. I made a mistake while saving the file and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the csv file rather than the loadtxt() function. The format in which I saved was not giving a proper .csv file(dont know why!-maybe I didnt save it at all). But there is a way to verify whether the csv file is saved in the right format or not. Open the .csv file using notepad. If the data has commas between them, then it is saved properly. And loadtxt() will work. If it shows some gibberish, then create it again and then check.